# Calling @Html.Action with string route value fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following..

```
@Html.Action("Index", "Presents", 
     new {@Model.GroupId, @Model.PresentId, Name = @Model.CurrentName })
```

With the following Model..

```
public class MyModel
{
        public long GroupId { get; set; }
        public long PresentId { get; set; }
        public string CurrentName { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the action though I am seeing CurretName as null.  If I go..

```
@Html.Action("Index", "Presents", 
     new {@Model.GroupId, @Model.PresentId, Name = "@Model.CurrentName" })
```

I'll get the actual text "@Model.CurrentName" for CurrentName.

Any clue how I get string values to pass properly when the source is a model?

Comment: I'm an idiot.. @Model.CurrentName is currently empty... going to request a delete on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you simply remove @ in front of Model?

Like this:

```
@Html.Action("Index", "Presents", 
 new {Model.GroupId, Model.PresentId, Name = Model.CurrentName })
```

Comment: +1 - You should only need to specify the `@` symbol once on that line.